# spark (yarn) remote app submit bash

Tags: bash, apache-spark, jenkins

I'm trying to deploy spark apps through jenkins. Manually I can do something like :

```
ssh -T -i ~/.ssh/keys/me.pem hadoop@....compute.amazonaws.com spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class myclass.myobject s3://mybucket/myjar1.0.jar
```

The problem I have is that spark-submit doesn't detach once the job is submitted to yarn. I have not found a command line option to detach after deploy. Any ideas on deploying through jenkins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a simple ssh command with --conf spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false arg will work actually.

Answer (score 1):

Add **nohup** at begening of your command and **&** at the end.

```
ssh -T -i ~/.ssh/keys/me.pem hadoop@....compute.amazonaws.com nohup spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class myclass.myobject s3://mybucket/myjar1.0.jar &
```

Comment: yah I guess I didn't think of using bash but this might work well. I would prefer an argument that gracefully detaches.

Comment: something I would have to test is how fast can I close the ternimal with nohup. I want to have this as a task in jenkins.